# How do I create a copy of a sidebar on the other side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a template.
It works exactly as it should: there's a black bar on the left that stretches to 100% of the page height.

But I honestly don't understand how to create a duplicate of this panel and put it to the right.

I tried using `float`, but that didn't work.
Can you please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style the side navigation */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Side navigation links */
.sidenav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.sidenav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the content */
.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>CSS Template</h2>
  <p>A full-height, fixed sidenav and content.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to achieve this:

- **Duplicate the sidebar markup and give them different class names (besides their common name `sidenav` for grouping common styles).**

Like so:

```
<div class="sidenav sidenav-left">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="sidenav sidenav-right">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

- **Position the navbars in different rule sets.**

Use a common class to group styles that are common to both of them, then place their unique positioning styles in separate rule sets as shown below:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
} 

.sidenav-left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
}

.sidenav-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```